# htaccess test stopped after RewriteCond is encountered

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, drupal

I want to redirect all `http://www.mywebsite.com/other/sub/paths` to `http://mywebsite.com/other/sub/paths`

I am using http://htaccess.madewithlove.be to see my htaccess url output before doing it on live site. I am able to redirect my pages, but the tests are stopped mid-way and the following is displayed:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.mywebsite\.com$ [NC]  This condition was met
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://mywebsite.com/$1 [L,R=301]
This rule was met, the new url is
http://mywebsite.com/index.php?q=sc?pract?aut The tests are stopped,
using a different host will cause a redirect
```

Is this an error that the tests are stopped ?
I have the following lines untested (they are after the RewriteRules where test was stopped)

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f     
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d     
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !=/favicon.ico   
RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]     
# Requires both mod_rewrite and mod_headers to be enabled.  
# Serve gzip compressed CSS files if they exist and the client accepts gzip.    
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Accept-encoding} gzip    
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.gz -s  
RewriteRule ^(.*)\.css $1\.css\.gz [QSA]    
# Serve gzip compressed JS files if they exist and the client accepts gzip.     
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Accept-encoding} gzip    
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.gz -s  
RewriteRule ^(.*)\.js $1\.js\.gz [QSA]  
#Serve correct content types, and prevent mod_deflate double gzip.  
RewriteRule \.css\.gz$ - [T=text/css,E=no-gzip:1]   
RewriteRule \.js\.gz$ - [T=text/javascript,E=no-gzip:1]
```

My site is hosted on drupal 6 if it is of any help.

Answer (score 0):

From http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/rewrite/flags.html

The [L] flag causes mod_rewrite to stop processing the rule set. In most contexts, this means that if the rule matches, no further rules will be processed. This corresponds to the last command in Perl, or the break command in C. Use this flag to indicate that the current rule should be applied immediately without considering further rules.

Comment: So is it harmful that the remaining code is not tested ? Will it cause any errors on my website which are not detectable easily ?

Comment: If the first rule doesn't match, then mod_rewrite will check the next rule. So, if the 301 redirect happens, no more processing occurs. But if the 301 redirect doesn't happen, the other rules are checked. So they should be tested. The way to test is to use a `mywebsite.com` hostname without the `www.`. The rules look OK to me.